# How to return the array (created by API data) using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am using node-fetch npm package to receive data using a specific API. In the code, I have written a forEach loop to fetch API response of every single element of the array (in my example the array is rows). But finally whenever I am returning the array and printing, the array showing a blank result ([]). I am new to NodeJS. Please help me with this problem.

What I want: An array of response (dataArr);

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(cl) {
    
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
      client_email: creds.client_email,
      private_key: creds.private_key,
    });

    await doc.loadInfo();

    const title='Sheet4';
    const rows = await getSheetByTitle(title);
    //const array_size=rows.length;
    //console.log(rows[0].keyword);
    const dataArr=[];

    const obj = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        rows.forEach(async (row) => {
            var data=row.keyword;
            fetch("https://api.url.com/")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(function(res) {
                dataArr.push(res);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
       
        console.log(dataArr);
    });
    // return dataArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of the array before it is getting populated.
Try this.

```
Promise.all(
  rows.map(row =>
    fetch(row)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => dataArr.push(res))
  )
).then(() => console.log(dataArr));
```

Comment: Hi Jatin, Thank you for your reply. But in the example, you have printed the dataArr inside the foreach loop. That means it will print dataArr total rows.length-1 times. I want the dataArr with all the API values and print it once only when all the API calls will be completed. After that, I want to return that dataArr (which contains all the API return values). How should I implement that? Could you please help me?

Comment: @Shushovan I have updated the code accordingly, you can just await that Promise.all() and return dataArr

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with your code is *forEach*. Each of the async callback function calls does return a promise, but you're throwing them away instead of awaiting them. As a rule of thumb, use `forEach` for synchronous operations only.

Here's what you can do with `Promise.all([...])`

```
try {
  const dataArr = await Promise.all(rows.map(async row => fetch(<your url>))
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```